# htaccess xampp not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need help with my .htaccess what i want is change this url

http://localhost/blog/admin/editar_articulo.php?accion=27

to

http://localhost/blog/admin/editar_articulo/27

But my code does not work. Is showing a server error 500, I have this code Iam using xampp

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/admin # in folder admin is where i have the .htaccess file
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^editar_articulo/([0-9]+)/?$ editar_articulo.php?accion=$1 [NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I tried this and worked

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^editar_articulo/(\w+)$ editar_articulo.php?accion=$1
```

But its not showing my css in the page what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in `<head>` tag create `<base>` tag to set all external links url

```
<head>
  <base href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycssfile.css">
</head>
```

browser read `href="css/mycssfile.css"` as `href="http://www.mywebsite.com/css/mycssfile.css"`